# Navigating from struts.xml to occurrence of action in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, struts2, eclipse-plugin

I have some code within struts.xml like:

```
   <action name="viewApplicationPDF" 
     class="com.xxx.abc.web.action.XApplicationPDFAction">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/templates/xApplication.jsp</result>
       </action>
```

I want to be able to quickly jump to the occurrences of the action "viewApplicationPDF" within jsp files containing the action usage, like:

```
   <a href="<s:url action="viewApplicationPDF"/>/s:url>Used here</a>
```

In spite of the fact that this jump pattern is quite frequent, I have not found a quick way to do this in Eclipse. Currently I have to do a "File Search" for "viewApplicationPDF" and then open the directory tree within the search results -- but all this is slow. Is there a plugin or some other tool to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no such plugins (at least that I'm aware of).

An alternative to what you've mentioned:

- Double-click on the word you want to search.
- Press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`G` or right-click on the word and select `References`-->`Workspace`.

This does the same search as what you mentioned.

Comment: Unluckily Ctrl+Shift+G does not work within struts.xml (it works only within *.java) for me.

Comment: @Amit Kumar, true, sorry, you'll have to find a struts2 plugin for Eclipse or write your own.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut for File Search:

Window > Customize perspective > Command Groups Availability > Search > Menubar details > File.

You'll get a tool tip for Key bindings. Click on the link and select the Binding input field. Click a combination of keys, say Shift+F and hit Apply.

Now you can select the text in the file and hit Shift+F+Enter and the search is on.

You can modify the File name patterns in the search dialog to suit.

(I'm using Helios distribution)

Also useful:

Install the AnyEdit tools plugin for Eclipse from http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/

Allows you to navigate to file under cursor (ctrl+alt+R) or open type under cursor (ctrl+alt+T).

Comment: I was looking for an indexed search. However, your answer certainly helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well its past a decade, still I am writing this for someone who just started using Eclipse. You may download the Plugin StrutsClipse.

Comment: Why? What does it do? How does it solve the problem, specifically? Can you [edit] your answer to explain? While you're at it, please provide an authoritative link to the plugin, so future readers don't need to search for it.